# Calling Facebook photos using helpers METEOR-JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor

I'm trying to call facebook profile photos using the following in Meteor.

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    avatar: function() {
        if (Meteor.user().services.facebook) {
        return "http://graph.facebook.com/" + Meteor    .user().services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large"; 
        }
        else
        {
            return "img/blank_avatar.png"
        }
    }
});
```

and I'm calling this by

```
<img src = "{{avatar}}">
```

In my browser console, I'm getting an error saying

> Exception in template helper: avatar

I really don't understand what is the problem...

Comment: Just to be sure that the real problem is on the helper and not on the accounts-facebook console.log the 2 return statment and looks what you get, if you get a correct url put it on the <img> tag with the static content, btw the helper looks good, also did you have another template helper named "avatar"?

Comment: @Ethaan Hey. Thank you for the response. I still can't seem to fix it. I do only have that one avatar helper. I've tried calling it different things but have not had success. Also, ''Meteor.user().services.facebook'' seems to not be working on my app for some reason. So is the return statement below it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets change that Facebook logic to the `server side`, on the `onCreateUser` method.

```
//server
    Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
       if(user.services.facebook) {
          user.profile = options.profile; 
          user.profile.picture = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
       }else if(options.profile){
          user.profile = options.profile;
       }
    return user
});
```

With that if some user login with `Facebook services` the `profile.picture` field will hold for us the `url` with the Facebook photo.

Now on the Client side

**JS**

```
    //client
    Template.foo.helpers({
      showProfile:function(){
        if(Meteor.user().profile){
          return userProfile.picture;
        }else{
         return "img/blank_avatar.png"
        }
      }
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <img src="{{showProfile}}" class='fbPic'>
      {{/if}
```

**CSS**

```
.fbPic {
  border-right: 1.5px solid;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I made yours the answer. However, is it not possible to have it with the logic that I have?

Comment: I changed ``userProfile.picture`` to ``return Meteor.user().profile.picture;``